# Increase space inside cells

Tags: tables

I created this table, but i want to increase the height of the rows so that the text would be centered and not hitting the horizontal lines.

I have this code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{||c | c | c | c||} 
\hline
 & EUROSTOXX50 & Nikkei225 & DAX30 \\ [1ex] 
\hline\hline
$R_{adj} ^2$ & 0,389  & 0,233  & 0,663 \\ [1.9ex] 
\hline
$\hat{\theta}$ & 0,623 & 0,157 & 0,482 \\[1.9ex] 
\hline
$\hat{\alpha} $& 0,165 & 0,133 & 0,497 \\[1.9ex] 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't fiddle with adding after each row  a spacing: you can obtain it with the `cellspace` package, which defines a *minimal* vertical padding in cells of columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). Additionally, you'll have a nicer layout with package `hhline`, which manages neatly the intersections of horizontal and vertical double rules:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array, cellspace, hhline}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{||*{4}{Sc|}|}
  \hhline {----}
  & EUROSTOXX50 & Nikkei225 & DAX30 \\
  \hhline{=:=:=:=}
  $R_\mathrm{adj} ^2$ & 0,389 & 0,233 & 0,663 \\
  \hhline{||----||}
  $\hat{\theta}$ & 0,623 & 0,157 & 0,482 \\
  \hhline{||----||}
  $\hat{\alpha} $& 0,165 & 0,133 & 0,497 \\
  \hhline{----}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

with use of `makecell` (first example) and `booktabs` (secon example) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, hhline}
\setcellgapes{5pt}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{center}
\makegapedcells
 \begin{tabular}{||*{4}{c|}|}
  \hhline {----}
  & EUROSTOXX50 & Nikkei225 & DAX30 \\
  \hhline{=:=:=:=}
  $R_\mathrm{adj} ^2$ & 0,389 & 0,233 & 0,663 \\
  \hhline{||----||}
  $\hat{\theta}$ & 0,623 & 0,157 & 0,482 \\
  \hhline{||----||}
  $\hat{\alpha} $& 0,165 & 0,133 & 0,497 \\
  \hhline{----}
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
or better:
  \begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$} *{3}{c}}
  \toprule
                    & EUROSTOXX50   & Nikkei225 & DAX30 \\
  \midrule
R_\mathrm{adj}^2    & 0,389         & 0,233     & 0,663 \\
\hat{\theta}        & 0,623         & 0,157     & 0,482 \\
\hat{\alpha}        & 0,165         & 0,133     & 0,497 \\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{document}
```